# limit foreach results

Tags: foreach, limit

I am working on a facebook app and I try to get user's friend list by zodiacal sign. However some of users have 20 friends on the same sign.. others 50 etc. and I want to limit the result to 10. I need some advices from an expert.

```
foreach($all_friends_profile as $profile)
{
  $frzodie  = star_sign($birthday);
  $frname = $profile->name;
  $frid = $profile->uid;
  $comp = "<div class=\"mod_frm mod_frm_margin clearfix\">
    <div class=\"pic\"><img src=\"https://graph.facebook.com/".$frid."/picture/\"></div>
    <div class=\"meta\">".$frname."</div>
    <div class=\"uiButton uiButtonSpecial\">Share</div></div>";

  if (strpos($frzodie,$randZodie) !== false) 
  { 
    echo $comp;   // **This must be limited to 10.**
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$count = 0;
foreach(...) {
    ...
    $count++;
    if($count >= 10) {
         break;
    }
}
```